# Is it possible to transfer sqlite file to watch os 2

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2

Can any one help me out on this problem. I am struggling to transfer the sqlite to watch os 2. If you have any example share with me or please give your suggestion on this

Comment: could you post some code showing what you've tried so far?

Comment: This is from iOS side       let fileURL = coreDataStack.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
        session.transferFile(fileURL, metadata: nil)

Comment: Have you implemented the `didFinishFileTransfer` delegate callback on the sending side? Does it get called with an error?

Answer (score 1):

Have not tried this for sqlLite files but works with audioFiles.
What I did is:

1. Turn ON App Group both on watch extension and main project.
2. Place file in App Group Container
   // I create the file there so my code is

   ```
   NSURL * urlOut = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: APP_CONECTIVITY_ID];
   urlOut = [urlOut URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.wav"];
   ```
3. Send via `WCSession sendMessage` the link, need to send as string so you will send `urlOut.absoluteString`.
4. Profit?

You should be able to use stuff like `sendMessageData` //reading the file as date beforhand.
and there is also this `WCSessionFileTransfer`.
But I haven't had a chance to try that yet.

Comment: For me image is getting transfer. Only sqlite file i am struggling